# Language of this finite state automaton?

Tags: automata, finite-state-machine

What would be the formal definition of the language for the following Finite State Automaton?

[image: FSA]

Comment: Finite sequences of $a$'s and $b$'s that either end with a $b$ or end with $ba$.

Comment: Is the word $b$ accepted or rejected by this automaton? What about $bab$?

Comment: @irchans The string $b$ wouldn't qualify as an accepted word right? Since it can also be returning to state $q_0$?

Comment: The fact that this has two $b$ arrows out of $q_0$ makes this not well-defined.

Comment: @CheyneH This is a nondeterministic finite state automaton, for which multiple (or no) transitions for a given pair of state and symbol is well-defined.

Comment: @Math1000 Gotcha, that's why I asked my question about $b$ and $bab$. The first comment is correct then.

Comment: Just "$b$" is fine.  You start in q0 and then transition to q1 and terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Your language consists of all words over $\{a,b\}$ ending in $b$ or in $ba$. You can write it as a regular expression:
$$ (a+b)^*b(\epsilon + a). $$